# Compare a variable with object and return element according to the value difference

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Since I'm not that good in JS, I will appreciate help here...

I have this array:

```
segments = [
    { state: 33, color: "red" },
    { state: 66, color:"yellow" },
    { state: 100, color: "green" }
]
```

Three variables:

```
goal = 100
currentValue = 26
percentage = currentValue * 100 / goal
```

I'm trying to write a function that compare percentage and state in the object, and return the color that accompanies the state. For example:

If percentage is < 33, should return "red".

If percentage is in between 33 & 66, has to return "yelow".

If percentage is > 66 or > goal, has to return "green".

So far I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
defineChartColor = (currentActivity, goal) => segments.find(segments => segments.state > percentage).color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check against `state`, not `value` of the object with `<=`. The equal sign is important to find exact values, like the last one of `100`.

```js
var segments = [{ state: 33, color: "red" }, { state: 66, color:"yellow" }, { state: 100, color: "green" }],
    goal = 100,
    currentValue = 26,
    percentage = currentValue * 100 / goal,
    getColor = (percentage, goal) => segments.find(({ state }) => percentage === goal
        ? state === 100
        : percentage <= state 
    ).color;

console.log(getColor(33, 100));
console.log(getColor(66, 100));
console.log(getColor(100, 100));
console.log(getColor(20, 20));
```

Comment: What happens if segments is not ordered?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nina-scholz. But It still needs to return green also when percentage is > goal.

Comment: @Emeeus, it needs a sorted array, as op has included.

Comment: @emeeus, good question. I realized that the function should take care of sort segments as first action.

Comment: @Aleval, please add some use cases and the wanted results. for unsorted data, you could sort in advance.

Comment: Yes, data has to be sorted. Then (cases):

if percentage < 33, return "red"

if percentage > 33 && < 66, return "yellow"

if percentage > 66 xor > goal, return green.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I only changed `percentage === goal` by `percentage > goal` and it worked as I need. Thank you very much!